# returning the location of the first value at a dataframe location that meets a condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['20:00', '23:00', '21:00', '21:00', '22:00', '22:00', '20:30'],
                   'traf': [100, 200, 25, 300, 100, 200, 100],
                   'num': [5, 3, 5, 6, 41, 34, 10]})
df = df.set_index(['time']).sort_index()
print(df)

        traf  num
time            
20:00   100    5
20:30   100   10
21:00    25    5
21:00   300    6
22:00   100   41
22:00   200   34
23:00   200    3
```

I am trying to write a function to aggregate my dataframe by values of column `df['traf']` and then report the 1st value in column `df['num']` that meets a condition.

here is example of what I am doing but I am not sure if this a right rough to go. Also, since I am dealing with a very large size dataframe, I am not sure if this way is efficient enough.

```
filter = df.groupby(["time"])['traf'].sum() >= 225
df.where(filter, inplace=True)
print(df)

         traf   num
time              
20:00    NaN   NaN
20:30    NaN   NaN
21:00   25.0   5.0
21:00  300.0   6.0
22:00  100.0  41.0
22:00  200.0  34.0
23:00    NaN   NaN
```

So from the above result, I want my output to be the first value in column num that is not NaN in this case 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `transform` with `sum` then `groupby` again using `first`

```
s=df.groupby(["time"])['traf'].transform('sum').gt(255)
df[s].groupby('time').num.first()
Out[207]: 
time
21:00     5
22:00    41
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

Or

```
df.loc[s,'num'].iloc[0]
Out[211]: 5
```